# why is "q" not defined in the function

Tags: javascript

why is (q) is not defined

```js
var query = function(n) {
  var q = "appear preson"
  n()
}
query(function n() {
  console.log(q)
})
```

Comment: Because it only exists in the other function.

Comment: Learn about variable scopes.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a `function` inside another `function` doesnot create a Closure. You need to declare the function inside another function to create a closure.

> A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared

In your case you can `q` as argument.

```js
var query=function(n){
  var q="appear preson"
  n(q)
}
query(function n(q){
    console.log(q)
  }  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code scope of `q` is upto the function only. And you try to access the same variable out of that function. You need to declare `q` outside of the function. Please see below code.

```js
    var q;
    var query=function(n){
     q="appear preson"

    n()
    }
    query( function n(){
      console.log(q)
    }  )
```